# uptrace/bun: can't parse array: "[]"

Tags: postgresql, go, orm

I am using [bun](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/uptrace/bun) as a ORM in a postgresql database with the following model:

```golang
type Photo struct {
  bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:photos"`

  ID          uuid.UUID    `bun:"type:uuid,default:uuid_generate_v4(),pk" json:"-"`
  URL         string       `bun:"column:url"`
  UploadedBy  model.User   `bun:"column:uploaded_by,type:jsonb"`
  Description string       `bun:"column:description"`
  Likes       []model.User `bun:"column:likes,type:jsonb,array"`
  Liked       bool         `bun:"type:bool,scanonly"`
  Date        time.Time    `bun:"column:date"`
  Metadata    Metadata     `bun:"column:metadata,type:jsonb"`
  Tags        []string     `bun:"column:tags,array"`
  EventID     uuid.UUID    `bun:"column:event_id" json:"-"`
  Event       *event.Event `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:event_id=id" json:"event,omitempty"`
}
```

In the `likes` field there is an array containing objects with the following structure:
`[{ "email": "email@example.com", "name": "My Name" }]`

Then in my repo I have the following code to create a query builder:

```golang
    qb := p.database.NewSelect().QueryBuilder()

    if eventID != "" {
        qb.Where("event_id = ?", eventID)
    }

    selectQuery := qb.Unwrap().(*bun.SelectQuery)
    likedSubQuery := p.database.NewRaw(`CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(COALESCE(likes, '[]')) AS obj
        WHERE obj->>'email' = ?
    ) THEN true ELSE false END`, email)

    var photos []Photo
    err := selectQuery.
        Model(&photos).
        Column("*").
        ColumnExpr("(?) AS liked", likedSubQuery).
        Order("date DESC").
        Limit(limit).
        Offset(offset).
        Scan(context.Background())
```

My column `likes` is formatted correctly, even the `liked` calculated field works correctly. However my query is throwing the following error:

`sql: Scan error on column index 6, name "likes": bun: can't parse array: "[]"`